# How to completely discard the occurrence of a string not matching the regex pattern?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am implementing a regex pattern to a list of strings. Example of such a string is:`"MNT-PUT-Y0-HAS90"`. There are other UNWANTED strings as well, like: `"MNT-PUT-HAS90"`.

When I execute the below code, I get "" for the unwanted one, which I guess how Regex works. And, I get `"MNT-PUT-Y0-HAS90"` for the wanted one.

The question is: How can I completely ignore the occurrence of MNT-PUT-HAS90. I want to retrieve results for string - `"MNT-PUT-Y0-HAS90"` only.

I have implemented the below code for this:

```
Store = a.Type == "Machines" ? 
string.Join(",", a.Info.Disk.Select(b => b.Store).
Select(x => Regex.Match(x, "[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-T[0-9]-[A-Z]+[0-9]"))) : null
```

I tried changing the code to the below, but it shows me an error: `"Cannot convert lambda expression to the intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"`

```
Store = a.Type == "Machines" ? 
    string.Join(",", a.Info.Disk.Select(b => b.Store).
    Where(x => Regex.Match(x, "[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-T[0-9]-[A-Z]+[0-9]")).ToString()) : null
```

**EDIT:**
Just tried this:

```
Store = a.Type == "Machines" ? 
        string.Join(",", a.Info.Disk.Select(b => b.Store).
        Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-T[0-9]-[A-Z]+[0-9]")).ToList()) : null
```

I get no error but do not get the desired output either.

Comment: Try `Regex.IsMatch(x, "^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+$")`. BTW, what type is `Store`?

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew.. Thank you so much.. it resolved my problem like I never had it... Wow!! Thank you so much :)
Store is of type string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
Regex.IsMatch(x, "^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+$")
```

See [**how this regex works**](https://regex101.com/r/qo8CkC/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `[A-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters
- `-` - a hypehn
- `[A-Z]+-`  -  - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters and a hyphen
- `[A-Z]+[0-9]+-` - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters, 1+ ASCII digits and then a hyphen
- `[A-Z]+[0-9]+` - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters, 1+ ASCII digits
- `$` - end of string.

Code:

```
Store = a.Type == "Machines" ? 
    string.Join(",", 
        a.Info.Disk
           .Select(b => b.Store)
           .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+$"))
    ) 
    : null;
```

If the match is expected anywhere inside a longer string, remove `^` and `$` anchors.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very easy solution to it but somehow I was missing it...
I did the below to resolve the issue:

```
Store = a.Type == "Machines" && a.Power == "on" && 
       string.Join(",", a.Info.Disk.Select(b => b.Store).
       Where(x => Regex.Match(x, "[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-T[0-9]-[A-Z]+[0-9]"))) != "" ?
       "Do your stuff" : null
```